# Why is my SELECT statement returning 0.0000 all the time?

Tags: ios, select, sqlite

Okay, I've been having massive problems with my SQLite3 SELECT statement. My app stores GPS co-ordinates inside my table as a double. It then retrieves them in the same as a double. My issue is that every time I try to retrieve them It returns 0.000000 as the value of my latitude/longitude.

I know the SELECT statement is valid as I tested it inside SQLiteBrowser, and I know that the DB is there as I have found it in my simulators documents, and opened it with SQLiteBrowser again.

If anyone can tell me why it's returning 0.000000 instead of 37.337434 (the actual value that's in the table) then I would appreciate the help!

```
-(double)getLatitudeBysourceMonitor:(NSString *)asourceMonitor andpositionNo:(NSNumber *)apositionNo {
double latitude;
NSLog(@"sourcemonitor:%@ positionno:%@",asourceMonitor, apositionNo);
// Open the database from the users filessytem
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *databasePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"GPS.db"];
if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &databaseHandle) == SQLITE_OK)
    NSLog(@"Database opened properly");
{
    // Setup the SQL Statement and compile it for faster access
    NSString *sqlStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT latitude FROM GPSJob;"];
    NSLog(@"Searching for values %@ and %d", asourceMonitor, [apositionNo intValue]);
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(databaseHandle, [sqlStatement UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"Statement prepared");
        while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) 
        {
            // Need to get data from database...
            latitude = sqlite3_column_double(statement, 3); 
            NSLog(@"%f", sqlite3_column_double(statement, 3));
        }
    }
    // Release the compiled statement from memory
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
        NSLog(@"Reading latitude as: %f", latitude);
        return latitude;
}
```

Comment: FYI - this was tagged as Xcode 4.2. Are you really using such an old and outdated version of Xcode? You REALLY need to upgrade if you are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calls to `sqlite3_column_double` aren't correct. The 2nd parameter needs to be an index into the list of columns returned by the query. You only query 1 column so the index must be `0`.

```
latitude = sqlite3_column_double(statement, 0);
NSLog(@"latitude = %f", latitude);
```

A few other issues. Only call `sqlite3_finalize` if you actually prepared the statement. Don't forget to close the database if you open it. Use `sqlite3_errmsg` to log an error if `sqlite3_open` or `sqlite3_prepapre_v2` fail.